# Is there function to know raster's size (KB) with python?

Tags: python

I am doing a script with python. There I have many raster in canvas (qgis) which I would like to know size in MB. I am searching function in python that give me this result.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try referring to [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080477/how-to-get-the-size-of-tar-gz-in-mb-file-in-python).  They are looking at zip files, but it should work fine for your raster file.

If you are using a type of raster that is made up of multiple files, then I would suggest getting the file size of each and summing it.

The code would be similar to:

```
import os
os.path.getsize(#your file here)
```

As the post says, you can shift it to MB like this:

```
os.path.setsize(#your file here) >> 20
```

Credit definitely goes to Mark Longair and his answer on the referenced form post.

Answer (score 3):

Using [hurry.filesize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hurry.filesize/) you could do something like this :

```
import os
from hurry.filesize import size

raster_size = os.path.getsize('YOUR_PATH_HERE')
size(raster_size, system=alternative)
```